# Unidentified Error Due to mistake in .kt file

Tags: kotlin

- **file:///C:/Users/sn/AndroidStudioProjects/ForPFL2/app/src/main/java/com/example/forpfl2/OrderLog.kt:36:82 Expecting a class body** error appears as soon as I build following code:

  ```
  package com.example.forpfl2

  import android.content.Context
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.widget.Button
  import android.widget.EditText
  import android.widget.Toast
  import com.android.volley.Response
  import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
  import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
  import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue
  import kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.CompletedContinuation.context

  class OrderLog : AppCompatActivity() {

      lateinit var editTextNumberSigned:EditText
      lateinit var rfdbtn:Button


      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_log)

          editTextNumberSigned = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberSigned)
          rfdbtn = findViewById(R.id.rfdbtn)

          rfdbtn.setOnClickListener {
              if (editTextNumberSigned.text.toString().isEmpty()){      //inserted curly
                  Toast.makeText(this@OrderLog, "Enter Job Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          }else {  //inserted curly

          val url =
              "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyx_FUwzu05qmsfL7jsQbYJwk37VNphQq5PcN7_G3e73m0aPU38MX4_upms_KKuLv1dlA/exec"

                  val stringRequest=object : StringRequest(Request.Method.Post.url);
              Response.Listner {
                  Toast.makeText(this@OrderLog, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORTGTH).show()
              }
                      Response . ErrorListner {
                  Toast.makeText(this@OrderLog, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORTGTH).show()
              })
                  {
              override fun getParams(): MutableMap<string, string> {
                  val params=HashMap<string, string>()
                  params["JobNumber"] =editTextNumberSigned.text.toString()
                  return params
              }
          }
          val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this@OrderLog)
          queue.add(stringRequest)
      }

          }
      }
  ```

This code is suppose to sent the data from android application to a google sheet. I have doubt on following line of my code:

```
val stringRequest=object : StringRequest(Request.Method.Post.url);
```

Comment: This code should end with `{}` instead of `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is very poorly formatted and has quite some syntactic mistakes, and looks as though it was just copied and pasted from somewhere without actually trying to make it work.

I looked into it and here is the actual problem:

```
val stringRequest=object : StringRequest(Request.Method.Post.url);

            Response.Listner {  //<- it's Listener
                ...
            }
            Response . ErrorListner { //<- it's Listener
                ...
            })
                {
            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<string, string> {
                val params=HashMap<string, string>()
                params["JobNumber"] =editTextNumberSigned.text.toString()
                return params
            }
```

According to the [Java API](https://javadoc.io/static/com.android.volley/volley/1.1.1/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.html#StringRequest-int-java.lang.String-com.android.volley.Response.Listener-com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener-),  `StringRequest` class takes 4 parameters in it's constructor:

> - *method* - the request Method to use
> - *url* - URL to fetch the string at
> - *listener* - Listener to receive the String response
> - *errorListener* - Error listener, or null to ignore errors

You pass those parameters by separating them via a comma, so:
`StringRequest('method', 'url', 'listener', 'errorListener')` which you replace by their actual value, so, the problem is that you, not only separated the method and the url with a dot, which tells the compiler that the `url` is a variable of the method, you also closed the `StringRequest` constructor with the `)` bracket, so the listeners were given out to the air.

Then, the listeners names are written wrong(Kotlin allows you to even emit those names), have spaces where there shouldn't be (Response . ErrorListner // Listner should be written as Listener)

Here is the full code:

```
class OrderLog : AppCompatActivity() {
  
    lateinit var editTextNumberSigned:EditText
    lateinit var rfdbtn:Button
  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_log)
  
        editTextNumberSigned = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberSigned)
        rfdbtn = findViewById(R.id.rfdbtn)
  
        rfdbtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (editTextNumberSigned.text.toString().isEmpty()){      //inserted curly
                Toast.makeText(this@OrderLog, "Enter Job Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {  //inserted curly
                val url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyx_FUwzu05qmsfL7jsQbYJwk37VNphQq5PcN7_G3e73m0aPU38MX4_upms_KKuLv1dlA/exec"

                val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.Post, url, 
                    { response ->
                        button.text = "Response is: ${response}"
                    },
                    { 
                        button.text = "That didn't work!" 
                    }
                ) { 
                    override fun getParams(): MutableMap<string, string> {
                        val params = HashMap<string, string>()
                        params["JobNumber"] = editTextNumberSigned.text.toString()
                        return params
                    }
                }
            }
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this@OrderLog)
            queue.add(stringRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doubts are correct. The proper syntax of defining anonymous object
(because it's the one) is:

```kotlin
// anonymous obj with inheriting
object : Type(constructorParams) {
    override fun methodToOverride(): Type {

    }
}
```

A better example:

```kotlin
interface Printable {
    val content: String
    fun print(): String
}

val pizzaDescription = object : Printable {
    override val content: String = "Pizza with pineapple"
    override fun print(): String = "[pizza]"
}
```

You can read more [here (Kotlin docs)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#inheriting-anonymous-objects-from-supertypes)